# Caching queries confusion, laravel

Tags: php, mysql, caching, laravel, memcached

If I cached mysql query data, such as the **number of profile views** for example, what if the data had been changed or if new data had been entered into a table before the expiration time of the cached data. Am I supposed to update the old cached data? What is the best approach in preventing this problem? I am using laravel, a php framework.  Does memcached solve this problem in laravel? What is the approach or the right laravel commands to deploy in preventing such problems?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem. It's caching. When you use cached data you expect that data may be not up to date. Depending on your system you can set cache lifetime to adjust your needs. For some systems cache may by valid for only just 1 minute, and for other it can be valid even one day.

If new data come from your application, when inserting new data to database, you can remove cache for particular table but it's often not so easy. It may depend on your system architecture and complexity of cache usage.

You should also think if number of profile views is really so important to be up-to-date. If you think yes - simply when you increase profile views number in database, remove cache for this profile but depending on how often this happens, it may cause that your cache won't be used at all (if for example this number is updated every 2-3 seconds).

So in general - if you want up-to-date data, don't use cache at all, if you use cache you agree that some data is not up-to-date.